# Pointer to a const member variable

Tags: c++, function-qualifier

I was wondering what the syntax was for a pointer to a constant member variable.

I know a pointer to a non-const member function and a pointer to a const member function are expressly different types, ie, the following are two distinct types:

```
typedef void (Foo::*Bar)(void);
typedef void (Foo::*ConstBar)(void) const;
```

I was wondering if the same could be said of pointers to non-const and const member variables, ie are the following two distinct types as well, and if so, what is the syntax of the latter:

```
typedef int (Foo::*var);
typedef int (Foo::*constVar) const; // Not the correct syntax.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The type of the pointer-to-member needs to match the type of the member:

```
typedef       int (Foo::*var);  // pointer to a data member of type 'int'
typedef const int (Foo::*cvar); // pointer to a data member of type 'const int'
```

The const-qualification of a member function is a part of its type, just like the return type  is a part of its type.

Comment: Ah, I see. I had used this syntax at one point but, since what I'm doing is all templated, it was conflicting with the function which took T (C::*Get)(void);

Answer (score 4):

Just to make it funnier:

```
typedef const int (Foo::*(Foo::*ConstBar)(void) const);
```

ConstBar is a pointer to a const-member function taking no arguments and returning a pointer to a const-member of type int.

A general tip of how to remember the syntax in your question: you just write it the way you would define the member of the class

```
void name(void) const; // const function
const int name; // const member
```

And then replace `name` by `(Foo::*name)`, resulting in:

```
void (Foo::*name)(void) const; // pointer to const function
const int (Foo::*name); // pointer to const member
```